# PowerShell - get command's result header names

Tags: windows, powershell, formatting

How to get in PowerShell command's result type? I'm interested how to achieve that from console command instead of searching documentation

For example: I type `dir` then command will return table with such headers

- Mode
- LastWriteTime
- Length
- Name

My questions are

1. how to run command to get result headers for dir (these four string)?
2. does `dir` command has any additional headers? If yes how to get them?

Comment: `dir` (alias to `Get-ChildItem`) returns fileinfo, and directoryinfo objects. If you want to see all the members and methods that are available to you, you can pipe to `Get-Member` or `GM` for short. If you'd like to select all properties than what is shown, you can pipe to `Select-Object` and specify individual properties, or all using `*`

Comment: If you're doing it interactively in a PowerrShell session you can just pipe to ```| format-list *``` to see a vertical list of each item with all its properties - you can also shorten and use the ```fl``` alias - e.g. ```PS> dir | fl *```

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Thanx, your answer is this what I almost need.  Command `dir | gm` returns all props and methods. Can I modify command to get only four properties visible after dir execution?

Comment: You can specify whatever properties you'd like to display using `Select-Object` such as, `dir | Select Name, Length` or any others youd like. The default display is governed by format files - *that aren't recommended to modify yourself*.

Comment: Yes I know, I would like to know default properties for any command. Dir is just an example

Comment: @AbrahamZinala please look on comment above, I don't want to modify default. I juest want to read it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement **[@AbrahamZinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala)** comment:

> `dir` (alias to [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)) returns [fileinfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo), and directoryinfo objects. If you want to see all the members and methods that are available to you, you can pipe to [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member). If you'd like to select all properties than what is shown, you can pipe to [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) and specify individual properties, or all using `*`

By default `Get-Member` hides a few members along with the `PSStandardMembers` property:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Get-Member -Name PSStandardMembers
```

These members will only reveal if you use the `GetMember -Force` switch:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Get-Member -Name PSStandardMembers -Force

   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
PSStandardMembers MemberSet  PSStandardMembers {DefaultDisplayPropertySet}
```

This property includes the members that are shown by default in the table format (aka ['... | Format-Table'](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table))

```
(Get-ChildItem -File)[0].PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedPropertyNames
LastWriteTime
Length
Name
```

> I have no clue why the specific `Mode` property also shows up in table format while it isn't actually listed here and [I would be please if someone can explain this part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77058602/where-does-the-display-property-mode-come-from)

The `Select-Object` will indeed remove this decoration:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Select-Object * | Format-Table  -Property @{ e='*'; width = 7 }

PSPath  PSParen PSChild PSDrive PSProvi PSIsCon Mode    ModeWit Version BaseNam Resolve Target  LinkTyp  Length Directo Directo IsReadO FullNam Extensi Name     Exists Creatio Creatio LastAcc LastAcc LastWri LastWri LinkTar UnixFil Attribu
        tPath   Name            der      tainer         houtHar Info    e       dTarget         e               ryName  ry          nly e       on                      nTime   nTimeUt essTime essTime teTime  teTimeU get       eMode     tes
                                                        dLink                                                                                                                   c               Utc             tc
------  ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ----    ------- ------- ------- ------- ------  -------  ------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ----     ------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
Micros… Micros… dir.ps1 P       Micros…   False -a---   -a---   File: … dir     P:\Sta…                     383 P:\Sta… P:\Sta…   False P:\Sta… .ps1    dir.ps1    True 9/7/20… 9/7/20… 9/7/20… 9/7/20… 9/7/20… 9/7/20…              -1 Archive
```

But you might simply create your own `DefaultDisplayPropertySet` on each object like this:

```
$DefaultDisplayPropertySet = [System.Management.Automation.PSPropertySet]::new(
    'DefaultDisplayPropertySet',[string[]]('Name', 'FullName')
)
$PSStandardMembers = [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo[]]$DefaultDisplayPropertySet
$Dir = Get-ChildItem -File | Select-Object * | Foreach-Object {
    $_ | Add-Member MemberSet PSStandardMembers $PSStandardMembers -PassThru
}
```

The object list (`$Dir`) has still all standard properties available, e.g.:

```
$Dir.LastWriteTime

Thursday, September 7, 2023 11:07:32 AM
```

But it only shows just the two default properties when outputted to the display:

```
$Dir

Name    FullName
----    --------
dir.ps1 C:\FullPath\Test.ps1
```

Comment: See [Where does the display property `Mode` come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77059163/1701026) for an explanation specifically on the `FileSystem` type.