# Where does the display property `Mode` come from?

Tags: powershell, formatting

As an extend on the earlier question [get command's result header names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77054590/1701026) from [**Jacek**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650148/jacek), I think I have been able to explain the general `DefaultDisplayPropertySet` concept in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77058461/1701026).
But I can't explain why the specific `Node` member is shown on a `Dir` ([`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)) command:

```
Get-ChildItem

    Directory: C:\Path

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---            9/7/2023 11:07 AM            383 Test.txt
```

As there is no `Mode` property listed in:

```
(Get-ChildItem -File)[0].PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedPropertyNames
LastWriteTime
Length
Name
```

Can somebody explain where this specific `Mode` property (column) is coming from?

Comment: If you would like to dig deeper at how mode is constructed: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/9ebeca3d6e1a133cf052dd01aab3d8fd1b724dcf/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/FileSystemProvider.cs#L1864-L1905 // and essentially `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider]::Mode((Get-Item .))` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DefaultDisplayPropertySet` is defined for a given type (say, `FileInfo`) in the `types.ps1xml` that ships with PowerShell - this is the output used if nothing else is defined.  If you look in there, it only defines the three properties you see in your output (`LastWriteTime`, `Length`, `Name`).  `Mode` is added to the output by the formatting file `FileSystem.format.ps1xml`, which over-rides the default.

Jeffrey Snover discusses this a bit here: [PSStandardMembers – The Stealth Property](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/psstandardmembers-the-stealth-property/)